# Embedding the application background image in Flex return 404 not found error in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

I'm using Flash Builder 3 to create an application. I need to set an background image for the application.I was trying to embedded background image for my Flex application, and this syntax works properly:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()" width="468" height="400" 
fontFamily="Verdana" fontSize="10" fontWeight="bold" 
themeColor="#FFFFFF" cornerRadius="10" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" backgroundImage="@Embed(source='../Assets/BG-468x350.gif')" borderColor="#111112" backgroundGradientAlphas="[1.0, 1.0]" backgroundGradientColors="[#CDEAD0, #CDEAD0]">
```

Above embedded image work properly, but In mozila(or any other browser) fir-bug, I had noticed that background flash image's http request  was getting a 404 Not Found error, while trying to retrieve an image at 
    `http://arvind.abcd.com/loan/loan-advice-india/@Embed(source=%27../Assets/BG-468x350.gif%27)`

I couldn’t figure out why this was happening, So please suggest me possible solution for that. Thanks in advance for giving your valuable time here.

Comment: please any one can give solution and hint for above problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know I am right or wrong as I am not a regular flex developer as i got task occasionally assigned to me. My Mean is that I don't know what the reason behind that error, why http request of background Image getting 404 not found error, but i got a alternate way to embedded a background image which not received http request, and hence not return 404 not found error.

The alternate way which i use is as:

1. firstly i declare a variable BackgroundImage as:
   `[Bindable]
   [Embed(source="../Assets/BG-468x350.gif")]
   protected var BackgroundImage:Class;`
2. Then assign declered BackgroundImage variable to predefine backgroundImage variable  using preinitialize method init(), which declered on `<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
   layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()" width="468" height="350">` 
   `public function init():void
         {
           Application.application.setStyle("backgroundImage", BackgroundImage);

         }`

I mention this solution is here for other user who may get similar error, but if any body know better solution the please update here. Thanks for all.